# Windows Media Player 12 - option to print "jewel case" labels?

Tags: windows-media-player, label

WHY doesn't the Windows Media Player 12 have the software to print "jewel case" labels like the older systems did?

With my old Windows Media on an XP system, after you burned a music disc you could use a label maker software that was installed in the Windows Media player itself and would come up when you inserted the disc to play it and clicked the "file" icon.   That system is NOT installed on the new Windows 7 based Media Player 12.

Is their a Windows Media plug-in for that or a program that Microsoft offers that does the same thing?   It's a real pain to NOT have that feature available.

Comment: How are we supposed to know _why_?  We're not Microsoft. ;)  Are you sure this wasn't already a plug-in in the past?  I ask, as I don't think any version of WMP ever did this inherently.

Comment: If all you want to know is how to get a similar feature, please change your question to primarily ask for that.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft discontinued that functionality long ago.  However, you can use iTunes to print labels and highly recommend it.

Here's a step-by-step video tutorial:  http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xhl9js_how-to-print-cd-jewel-case-inserts-from-itunes_news

Hope this helps!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Winter Fun Pack 2003 installs a Plus! CD Label Maker plug-in for WMP that allows you to do just that (it's possibly even the same as the XP functionality you're referring to).

Since the Winter Fun Pack doesn't have a page on the Microsoft website anymore, here's the direct download link:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/a/8/ba836c39-01ab-4071-954d-c99d49a672ef/WinterPlayerPack.msi

Even though this software also has "WMP9 Series" in its name, it should still work fine on WMP 12.

Answer (score -1):

Old timer converting cassetts to cd and making playlists in media player.   After completing playlist I use my phone camera to take picture of playlist on screen and then email it to myself. I then copy image and send and save it to a publisher file where I can make labels for cd case.  Not a great tech solution but it works for me.

Comment: http://www.take-a-screenshot.org/